# How can I rotate an Avalonia app by 90 degrees?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I would like to rotate my Avalonia App 90 degrees. I am not running the app under X11, so If possible this should be done using XAML/code.

I have experimented with a Transform in the app

```
<Style Selector="......">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But this has some problems:

1. Screen width/height is not taken into account causing things to be stretched.
2. I have added the transform at the main layout component (Grid). Some buttons in the grid have a flyout. The flyout is not rotated.

How can I assure the app is rotated by 90 degrees taking into account screen area (no stretching) and make sure that everything is rotated?

Comment: This is a new one on me. I've never seen a request for this on any platform before. I can't think of any reliable way of doing this and having *any* and *every* control be aware of it's rotation. Controls simply are not built with this sort of thing in mind, I'm not even sure Avalonia is completely right-to-left compatible yet even. I can't even think of any other UI tech that could do this out the box without significant customisation. You're going to have to customise almost everything you use to achieve this I suspect.